# Android - How to place image/imagebutton under each other discarding transparent background?

Tags: android, image, background-image, imagebutton

How to place images/image buttons under each other s.t the transparent background wont separate them?

Example of the problem:

[image: Example of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove the empty area from the canvas of the images. But, you can achieve the result by giving negative marginTop to the descending view.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to inflate number of images Icon inside  zigzag lines. SO for that You can make a custom layout which contains your ZigZag designs. Let me know How are you setting those zigzag lines ? Is there any dynamic data is coming or its statically.

First create a Layout for row there is a Layout with stroke with 2dp.
 Now If you have that ZigZag colored images then 
    `android:background =   @drawable/YourImagZigZagImage"` in that layout.
 Now create a TextView inside that layout and define below properties.

**Setting TextView Into Image**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Image 1"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```